# apigClientFactory not defined

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm using APIGW Generated SDK for javascript, and I have sourced all the files and get no errors there, but I get an error on this line:
`var apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient();`

which makes sense, because I don't see any sources that point to anything called "apigClientFactory", nor are there any instructions on instantiating anything called "apigClientFactory" as an object/variable or anything, so I'm confused as to what this is supposed to be referencing?

The instructions [Aws amazon docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk-javascript.html) start with this and never reference where this factory component is from, hence the error...

Comment: The apigClientFactory should be generated by API Gateway for your API. You can read the code in `apiClient.js` file

Answer (score 3):

I just found out on a call with AWS support that **the SDK generator tool doesn't currently know how to handle ANY methods** in your API and will ignore them.

Therefore, if you generate an API with only ANY methods (and no specific GET / POST / etc), the SDK generator tool will not include the `apiClient.js` file that includes the `apigClientFactory` you need and you will receive the `apigClientFactory not defined` error you mention above.

Comment: This explanation is mentioned in the AWS doc but What is the solution for that?

Answer (score 2):

You can include this

```
var apigClientFactory = require('aws-api-gateway-client').default;
```

Comment: what is the '.default' for?